# Dask merge behaves differently on how left and right

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I want to merge two [Dask DataFrames](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html%22Dask%20DataFrame%22)  and it seems that the left merge works, while the right one does not:

```
result_dd = df_dd1.merge(df_dd2, how='left', on=['id','date']).fillna(0)
#result_dd = df_dd2.merge(df_dd1, how='right', on=['id','date']).fillna(0)
```

First one works, while the second one causes the exception:

> ```
> ValueError: The columns in the computed data do not match the columns 
>     in the provided metadata
> ```

The `df_dd1.dtypes` are:

```
date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

The `df_dd2.dtypes` are:

```
date         datetime64[ns]
count        float64
dtype: object
```

I tried to reproduce the problem on simple data, but I could not (on artificial example it worked both ways).

Do you have any idea what could be a problem?

**Edit 1:**

I do not have any `NaT`/`NaN` values. At least `isnull().sum()` returns 0 for both frames.

Heads of the frames are as follows (the first one is not empty, but head returns empty frame): `df_dd1.head()`:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [date]
Index: []
```

For `df_dd1.head(npartitions=-1)` I get:

```
                date
id  
00002           2017-05-08
00002           2017-05-09
00002           2017-05-10
00002           2017-05-11
00002           2017-05-12
```

And the `df_dd2`.head():

```
      date              count
id                                               
0006d 2017-12-27        1.0
0009f 2017-10-28        2.0
000ba 2017-10-28        2.0
000cd 2017-11-14        1.0
00153 2017-12-17        1.0
```

Comment: do you have null values or NaT values in one of your df ?

Comment: Could you give us the head of each df please ?